# How to use defined data as function or class name?

Tags: php, oop

I defined a data like below..

```
define('INDEX_CONTROLLER', 'test');
```

And I want to use that like below..

```
require_once 'controllers/' . INDEX_CONTROLLER . '.php';
$this->controller = new INDEX_CONTROLLER();
```

I'm getting error that below..

> Fatal error: Class 'INDEX_CONTROLLER' not found in
>   /var/www/own/boot.php on line 13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it equal to a variable and then call it:

```
$controller = INDEX_CONTROLLER;
$this->controller = new $controller();
```

Comment: I have thinked that, is it possible without using variables?

Comment: I don't think so.  The reason you are getting the error is that PHP is trying to create a class 'INDEX_CONTROLLER'.  There is no way to tell if you want to use the constant or if you actually have a class `INDEX_CONTROLLER`.

Answer (score 2):

Better use Reflections

```
DEFINE('INDEX_CONTROLLER', 'test');
$rc= new ReflectionClass(INDEX_CONTROLLER);
$this->controller = $rc->newInstance();
```

or in one line if you use php5.4+

```
$this->controller = (new ReflectionClass(INDEX_CONTROLLER))->newInstance();
```

You can read more about Reflections here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php